# Assigning a string to an element of an array?

Tags: c++, string

I want to write a program that calculates a final grade of a class based on weighted averages, and I'm in the stage of prompting the user for the names of each category (eg. 'Homework', 'Quiz', etc). I have it set up to ask the user how many categories they have, and then ask them each one individually, and then save each category name as a string into an array element. I know its probably easier to use vector class, but I'd like to do it this way if at all possible.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "How many grade categories are there for this class? ";
  cin >> categories;


  int * categorynames = new int[categories];

  for (int i(0); i < categories; i++)
  {
    string text;
    cout << "Name of category: ";
    getline(cin, text);
    categorynames[i] = text;
  }
```

When I compile, I'm getting an error of "cannot convert std::string to int in assignment."

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2):

first of all you should change the type of `categorynames` into `string *` , also I noticed that `getline` is giving a whitespace as a first value (when i=0) and then will get the correct input for the rest, so change it to `cin>>categorynames[i]` , like this :

```
        string * categorynames = new string[categories];

        for (int i = 0; i < categories; i++)
        {
            //string text;
            cout << "Name of category: \n";
            cin>>categorynames[i];
            //getline(cin, text);
            //categorynames[i] = text;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't 
  `int * categorynames = new int[categories];` be `std::string *categorynames = new std::string[categories];`?
and I think you can remove `text` and use `getline(cin, categorynames[i]);`